# Trying to convert VB.NET code to C#. IsDBNull issue

Tags: c#, vb.net

I dont know how much code you would need but if you would like more id be happy to oblige

here is my attempt so far:

```
if(AliasNum == null || IsDBNull(AliasNum)
    return
```

Here is the VB code that Im trying to convert

```
If AliasNum = Nothing Or IsDBNull(AliasNum) Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: How is AliasNum declared?

Comment: You can look at the Convert.IsDBNull method, or try a comparison to DBNull.Value.

Comment: You probably want `if(AliasNum == null || AliasNum == DbNull.Value)`

Comment: AliasNum = ((TextBox)gvAliases.FooterRow.FindControl("InsertAliasNum")).Text;

Comment: And what errors are you getting with your conversion?

Comment: The name 'IsDBNull' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`DBNull.Value.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) Method to determine if the value is equal to [`DBNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull_members%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

```
if(AliasNum == null || DBNull.Value.Equals(AliasNum)
   return
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, AliasNum is of type `string`.  Maybe you want:

```
if (AliasNum == null || AliasNum.Length == 0)
    return;
```

Comment: If `AliasNum` is a string, why not use `string.IsNullOrEmpty(AliasNum)`?

Comment: I cut my teeth on .NET 1.1.  I don't think `IsNullOrEmpty` existed then.

Comment: you are correct, just checked and it looks like it was implemented in 2.0

Answer (score 0):

The "IsDBNull" function you are calling in the original VB code is from the Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information module.  The closest .NET equivalent is the System.Convert.IsDBNull method:

```
if (AliasNum == null || System.Convert.IsDBNull(AliasNum))
{
    return;
}
```

Also, the original "AliasNum = Nothing" syntax suggests that "AliasNum" is an instance of a value type, so you may need to change "AliasNum == null" to "AliasNum == default value of the type of AliasNum".